# Hive tables not shown in /user/hive/warehouse

Tags: hive, hue

I have created 2 DBs:

- DB1 'Airline',
- DB2 'Students'.

I can see DB1 in Hue browser. But cannot see its tables inside `/user/hive/warehouse/Airline.db/`.

I can see tables of Students.db in `/user/hive/warehouse/Students.db`. But cannot see it in hue browser.

Is there anything I need to set?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an acces to Hive CLI? If yes, try run command:

```
describe database Airline;
```

You should see  something like that:

```
Airline Airline Hive database   hdfs://<host-fqdn>:8020/apps/hive/warehouse public
```

This is how you can find location of database. You can run the same command for 'Student' database.